# Large durable wireless mouse

Tags: gaming, pc, wireless, mice

I've been using mice like the below for a while, and am looking to upgrade to something with a higher build quality.

[image: Patuoxun full-size wireless mouse]

I really like the feel and the button layout, but within a year or two the wheel and the thumb buttons starts getting very dodgy. The thumbs frequently register both buttons when you only click one, the wheel scroll is 50/50 whether it will register in the direction you want, it gets harder to do a wheel click without also registering a scroll, and the latest one has left-right wheel controls that are now permanently stuck on.

While I could continue to work around issues in software and buying new copies of the same cheap mouse, I'd rather pay more for something that lasts longer.

However, it's hard to find something that doesn't immediately jump to way more complex and expensive than I need like the Logitech MX Master. Is there something available in between?

Must have:

- Wireless
- Full-size ergonomic (~3 inch wide)
- No need for mat
- Lasts more then two years

Nice to have:

- Adjustable DPI
- 6-button (two thumb buttons)
- Clicking rather than smooth wheel scroll

Comment: For reference, the pictured model is £10.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the [**Logitech MX Master 3S**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09HM94VDS) is actually really try the option for your need.

- Wireless (either Bluetooth or - the potentially more reliable - included Logi Bolt USB receiver)
- Full-size ergonomic, 3.3 inch wide
- No need for mats, even works on glass
- While I can't tell for sure how long it will last, Logitech is from the top of the line, and I've used other mice from then for 6+ years without a hiccup
- Adjustable tracking sensitivity (200-8000 dpi (can be set in increments of 50 dpi)
- 7 buttons (Left/Right-click, Back/Forward, App-Switch, Wheel mode-shift, Middle click)
- Scrolling mode can be switched with a button

[image]

Since you want cheaper then perhaps the the older generation **Logitech MX Master 2S** which is like $70.

Comment: "way more complex and expensive than I need like the Logitech MX Master"

Comment: Oops  not sure how I missed it. But TBH MX Master is really the answer. Maybe the older Logitech MX Master 2S that you get for like $70. I don't think there is anything with comparative for less.

Comment: The 2S does look a better option (though they don't sell it direct in the UK). It baffles me that there's nothing in the same format but without the Flow stuff and the multi-mode scrolling at around £30-40.

Comment: I went for it in the end. Disappointed to find there's no rest for the little finger, but overall should be good.